# What do I need to do, function to specify certain things

Tags: python

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time

service = Service('/usr/local/Caskroom/chromedriver/118.0.5993.70/chromedriver-mac-x64/chromedriver')


def get_driver():
    # Set options to make browsing easier
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_argument("disable-dev-shm-usage")
    options.add_argument("no-sandbox")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches",
                                    ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_argument("disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")


    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    driver.get("https://automated.pythonanywhere.com")
    return driver

def clean_text(text):
    """Extract only the temperature from text"""
    output = text

def main():
    driver = get_driver()
    time.sleep(2)
    element = driver.find_element(by="xpath", value="/html/body/div[1]/div/h1[2]")
    clean_text(": ")
    return element.text


print(main())
```

To get the specific temp rather then the full line of text "Average World Temperature Now: 24" As you can see I have created a function to clean the text but it won't allow me to type "`output = text.split(": ")`".

I have tried to do a lot of things but none worked. When I tried

```
def clean_text(text):
    """Extract only the temperature from text"""
    output = text.split(": )
```

It won't allow me to do it, .split() function isn't available. Then I took that bit of code ": " and placed it down here:

```
def main():
    driver = get_driver()
    time.sleep(2)
    element = driver.find_element(by="xpath", value="/html/body/div[1]/div/h1[2]")
    clean_text(": ")
    return element.text
```

It still isn't doing what I want it to do, extract just the temp rather then the entire line.

Comment: "it won't allow me to type": how is it stopping you?

Comment: Your intended function `output = text.split(": ")` should work, but it looks like you're simply providing the string `": "` to the `clean_text()` function. You want to provide the full string returned from your xpath element query. If `element` is the string then you should do `temp_string = clean_text(element)` and finally `return temp_string`.

Comment: Please be specific about the error that happened when you tried the `split(": ")` solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a number of issues, but hopefully corrections below get you pointed in the right direction.

```py
...
def clean_text(text):
    """Extract only the temperature from text"""
    # you want to do the actual string manipulation here
    output = text.split(": ")

    # if you want to actually use the result, you need to return it
    # "output" is a list of strings, splitting where the ":" was.
    # note that this isn't very robust, but may function for your purpose
    return output[-1]

def main():
    driver = get_driver()
    # time.sleep(2) # probably not necessary?

    element = driver.find_element(by="xpath", value="/html/body/div[1]/div/h1[2]")
    # look at the docs for selenium to see what it's returning - "element" isn't 
    # just a string!

    # you want to provide the actual full string that you're pulling from the 
    # webpage to the clean_text() function
    temperature = clean_text(element.text)

    # now return the extracted temperature number
    return temperature
```

Comment: `output` is a list, not a number.

Comment: The temperature is `int(output[1])`.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, this is what happens when you try to answer things too quickly... will edit the "corrected" code.

Comment: Yes, it's also not clear if they want a numerical value, or just the string.

Comment: Temperature is a number, I can't imagine why they'd want the string. But the important part is extracting the list element.

Comment: @tdpu ty so much, can I get a crypto address to give you a tip please? I have to read up on this but it appears like it worked 

Comment: @lacekim no need for a tip - glad I could help.

Comment: @Barmar, they may simply want to insert the temperature in another string/label, or send it, stringified, over the wire... yes you should probably parse and validate the temperature returns a "sane" number, but it's not necessary.